# windows form keeping datagridview up to date

Tags: c#, forms, datagridview

I have a datagridview that is connected to a table.  The datagridview changes when certain actions are made, but I would like it to refresh (i.e. reload the grid from a datatable that I create) even if the user isn't doing anything so the data the user sees is up to date.  What is the best way to do this?  Thanks!

Comment: Using a timer could do the trick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a timer like this

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.Interval=1000; // time in milliseconds
        timer.Tick+=new EventHandler(timer_Tick);
    }

    void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       //Do your update here
    }
```